# Cannot add multiple registrations for QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I'm following a [simple tutorial](https://youtu.be/Bo5Og2fb1CA) from Qt's website for creating a QtQuick application. But I can't get the expected output, instead I get the error 'Cannot add multiple registrations for QtQuick' in Qt6Core.dll. After browsing for a while, I can't find any relevant solution to this.

Note: .dll file is not missing, it's throwing the error.

Environment:

- OS: Windows 11
- QT Creator version: 9.0.1 Community
- QT Version: 6.4.2
- Kit: Desktop MSVC 2019 x64

Code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column{
        id: column
        width: 125
        height: 75
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        TextField{
            id: textField
            placeholderText: "Enter anything..."
        }

        Button{
            id: button
            text: "Click to open"
            onClicked: {
                myPopup.open()
            }
        }
    }

    Popup{
        id: myPopup
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 150
        height: 75
        closePolicy: "Close on Escape"

        Column{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 10
            Text{
                text: textField.text
            }

            Button{
                text: "Close"
                width: 100
                onClicked: {
                    myPopup.close()
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not mentioning the version in import as Qt6 don't require it.

Expected result: Should open a window with an input field and a button.
Actual result: Error stating "Cannot add multiple registrations for QtQuick"

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code, I get `Invalid property assignment: unknown enumeration`. The error occurs on your Popup closePolicy. To resolve the problem, you must use the enumerated type not a string, i.e.  change:

```
    closePolicy: "Close on Escape"
```

to:

```
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape
```

You can [Try a working version of your code online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADhnichVJNa4QwEL3nVwRP7SXYwlLwWNlCT3Whf8DGsIbGTIgjrRT/e5O4UeLK7pwm782X7yk7AxbpCU+D5N9EJk9WgkYLqiekqs+C/hHqogQ1dHrOfcimoDxgC/QjG2wL+vR8WKBWyHOLBX1ZoVrzFmzPuNAo7LsuqKmty8lS8Sl+8U0K1dB1XVyJkUsYo2ouWlCNsL65oNnRD3e7RmylPjPGsqVhWje9Doigd9Z8BSKBcR5cKicRRaBghM6SCtCBFK4/neijGyswg2G+7eExoSeSZpcDQz1NFb9MuS9mLIieHPJbnnAFvajAXT8W815WeuhDH3teG7EqNv8Gm++7e4WP3tTcWeFuyRPcG7aj1yz3Yjfz2Ua15Llr5TooC9+TXbFRnzy/om7a6SNaGtTbeDpfuPuIJk//nGfc4A==)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#closePolicy-prop